# Lite Speed Cache causing a blank page/space on the website when I use animation

Tags: wordpress, bridge, litespeed

I am using the Lite Speed Cache plugin on the following websites:

```
https://curveaccountants.com.au/
https://musclejointbone.com.au/
https://northernspinal.com.au/
```

These sites use the Qode Bridge theme. I am often getting a blank page/space whenever I animate an element. This issue is resolved by purging the cache. I am not sure what is causing the issue with the animated elements/section. I’ve reset the LiteSpeed Cache setting to default and I still have this issue.

What is the potential solution for this? I am running my website on a Lite Speed server so I don’t want to replace the plugin with different cache plugin.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: did you solve this? I am having the same issue with this theme

Comment: @snake, I ended up removing the Bridge theme and had to rebuild the website with the DIVI builder to fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer yet... but I found some issues with the saved values of the animations hope this helps pin point things a bit more.  Makes me think something is not saving correctly...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, mate. At least now I know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues (completely blank, white screens on multiple websites, not always on all pages). The solution was to turn off the Guest Mode in Litespeed Cache plugin and Purge All. I don't know why this worked, just that it did.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off Serve Stale Content and it worked for me.
Guest Mode didn't help